# Me aparece la exepcion null pointer y no se porque

Tags: java, java-swing, java-awt

tengo un error en el siguiente código: (Solo  he copiado el codigo de la clase donde me sale el error).

```
import java.awt.Checkbox;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelCentro extends JPanel {

    private Box verticalBox;

    Box tipoBox, tipoDeMensajeBox, mensajeBox, confirmarBox, opcionBox, entradaBox;

    public PanelCentro() {

        verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        tipoBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        tipoDeMensajeBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        mensajeBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        confirmarBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        opcionBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        entradaBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        agregarHorizontal(tipoBox);
        add(verticalBox);

    }

    public void agregarHorizontal(Box caja) {
        if (caja.equals(tipoBox)) {
            JPanel tipoJPanel = new JPanel();
            tipoJPanel.setLayout(new EnLinea());
            tipoJPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Mensaje"));
            tipoJPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Confirmar"));
            tipoJPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Opcion"));
            tipoJPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Entrada"));
        // tipoBox.add(tipoJPanel);  
           verticalBox.add(tipoBox);
    }
}
```

Cuando descomento la instrucción "tipoBox.add(tipoJPanel)",(podéis verla al final del código) me aparece  la conocida exepcion null pointer exception , a que se debe?

Comment: Leé esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados?r=SearchResults&s=1|24.1016

Comment: Ya arregle el problema.